# how to remove item in nested array on mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, updates

I need to remove item in nested array, following is my document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58760d8caa30c585ef8d3beb"),
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "item" : "A",
            "score" : 5.0,
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "q" : 1.0,
                    "a" : 4.0
                }, 
                {
                    "q" : 1.0,
                    "a" : 5.0
                }, 
                {
                    "q" : 2.0,
                    "a" : 6.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "item" : "B",
            "score" : 8.0,
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "q" : 1.0,
                    "a" : 7.0
                }, 
                {
                    "q" : 1.0,
                    "a" : 5.0
                }, 
                {
                    "q" : 2.0,
                    "a" : 9.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to remove all item in answers which q equal 1.0, following is expect document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58760d8caa30c585ef8d3beb"),
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "item" : "A",
            "score" : 5.0,
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "q" : 2.0,
                    "a" : 6.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "item" : "B",
            "score" : 8.0,
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "q" : 2.0,
                    "a" : 9.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I used:

```
db.getCollection('test').update({"results.answers.q":1},
                                { $pull: {"results.$.answers": {q:1} } },
                                { multi: true })
```

But got:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58760d8caa30c585ef8d3beb"),
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "item" : "A",
            "score" : 5.0,
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "q" : 2.0,
                    "a" : 6.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "item" : "B",
            "score" : 8.0,
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "q" : 1.0,
                    "a" : 7.0
                }, 
                {
                    "q" : 1.0,
                    "a" : 5.0
                }, 
                {
                    "q" : 2.0,
                    "a" : 9.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

in item B there still have embed documents which q equal 1

How can I do?

Comment: Did you try $pullAll ?

Comment: @SagarReddy `$pullAll` operator requires exact match on the whole object, so I don't believe it can help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this result with a single query, unless someone can think of something really smart with `$where` operator. Usage of positional operator implies that you can only target a single array element (in your case it is a single `results` element), and this usage is a must in any subarray pulls.

An ugly workaround here is to perform this update **N** times where **N** is the length of `results` array. This approach will do the job, but obviously it will be a huge performance issue if these arrays are large.

Answer (score 0):

using the below query will work for you. For more info regarding $pull please visit https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

```
db.getCollection('test').update({},{ $pull: {"results":{"answers": {$elemMatch:{q:1} }} }},{ multi: true });
```

Comment: Your update removes the whole `results` elements instead of particular `answers` ones, hence it does not satisfy the output requirements specified by the author.

Comment: There is also no need in `$elemMatch` operator when dealing with a single query condition. You could do something like this to achieve the same result: `$pull: { "results" : { "answers.q" : 1 }}`

Comment: Yes, @Imperator is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can now achieve this with $pull, as per the MongoDB docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull-array-of-documents